# EPIPE (Broken Pipe) Bug while using FileTransfer-plugin with cordova 2.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have a cordova 2.0 app for android. I use the FileTransfer Plugin, to load some Data to my server. The first time, the upload is performed, everything works fine. But then I get a EPIPE (Broken Pipe) error. If I simply push the upload-button again, it works.

How can I prevent the error?

```
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497): Error getting HTTP status code from connection.
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.writeHex(ChunkedOutputStream.java:102)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.writeBufferedChunkToSocket(ChunkedOutputStream.java:128)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.close(ChunkedOutputStream.java:118)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:804)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.createFileTransferError(FileTransfer.java:384)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.upload(FileTransfer.java:316)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:85)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:192)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
09-28 17:31:12.304: W/FileTransfer(29497):  ... 14 more
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497): {"target":"http:\/\/10.100.150.173:8081\/mobile110\/upload","source":"content:\/\/media\/external\/images\/media\/30","code":3}
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.writeHex(ChunkedOutputStream.java:102)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.writeBufferedChunkToSocket(ChunkedOutputStream.java:128)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.write(ChunkedOutputStream.java:77)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.upload(FileTransfer.java:261)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:85)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:192)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
09-28 17:31:12.319: E/FileTransfer(29497):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: Not really, I just submitted the file again.

Comment: Ah darn. This problem is a real bummer, hardly any help around and barely anything to understand the cause.

Comment: I also have this problem using phonegap 2.1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've also been grappling with random intermittent HTTP status errors and have employed a workaround using a var to store retry status.  I then increment this var if the transfer fail callback is called and retry the upload function up to 3 times (though it has not required more than 1 retry):

```
var imageRetry = 0; // if upload errors, retry 3 times
...
// file transfer fail callback
function fail(error) {
    if(imageRetry < 3){
         imageRetry++;
         uploadPhoto(); // call upload function again
    }else{
        // normal failure handling
    }
}
```

Notes: Server is white listed and I've tried disabling chunkedMode as well with no success. I'm also not using normal or self-signed SSL. In my case, user can filter a photo before uploading.  If no filter is applied, upload always succeeds.  If user tries applying any filter, upload randomly fails with error code 3.

(And yes, I know this solution is not totally ideal, but it's better than an unrecovered failure.)

Comment: looks like no choice, I have to deploy the same method